# Quitar duplicados en sql Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Amigos tengo un problema con un query que hice, lo que sucede es que quiero consultar los registros donde solo me traiga los registros que estén duplicados y que la unica diferencia es que en uno si tenga su numero de telefono y el otro no, los que no estaría como en 0, por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La imagen de arriba vendría siendo los registros que se se van a poblar desde el excel a la bd, el aplicativo por defecto le va asignar un 0 al campo vacío, como se ve en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora lo que quiero hacer es solo traerme el que solo esté poblado, es decir, desde bd mayor a 0, pero aparte también traerme los 0 que no están duplicados, espero y me dé a entender, es el query que hice pero desafortunadamente me omite también los que no son duplicados:

```
SELECT 
    CTA_QUE_FACTURA, CTA_NACIONAL,
    CTA_CONSOLIDADA, CTA_INDIVIDUAL,
    FECHA_CORTE, TIPO_DOCUMENTO,
    REGION, NUM_TELEFONO, UUID_RELACIONADO,
    NUM_PARCIALIDAD, SEQ_NUM_FINEQ,
    SALDO_ANTERIOR, IMPORTE_PAGADO,
    SALDO_INSOLUTO, FECHA_PAGO,
    SERIE,FOLIO, IMEI_SAC_PHONE,
    IMEI_FINEQ, NUM_LOTE_PAGO,
    TIPO_LOTE_PAGO, SECUENCIA_LOTE_PAGO,
    METODO_PAGO_M2K, NOMBRE_CLIENTE,
    RFC_RECEPTOR, ORIGEN_PAGO,
    USUARIO_PAGO, ACCT_ID, 
    ESTATUS_PAGO, FECHA_CREACION_BES 
FROM 
    complemento_pago_fact 
WHERE 
    folio in 
    (
        SELECT  
        CONCAT(FOLIO,'') 
        FROM COMPLEMENTO_PAGO_FACT
        WHERE 
        IND_PROCESADO= 0 
        AND to_char(fecha_creacion, 'DD/MM/YY')= '24/09/21'         
        GROUP BY FOLIO
        HAVING COUNT(*)>0
    ) 
    and NUM_TELEFONO >=0;
```

Les agradeceria si me pueden ayudar por favor, quedo al pendiente de alguna duda o comentarios.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `ROW_NUMBER()` para asignarle un número a cada fila del grupo de acuerdo a tu criterio. Luego sólo basta con filtrar el resultado usando este número.

Por ejemplo, puedes hacer:

```
select *
from (
  select t.*,
    row_number() over(
      partition by cta_que_factura 
      order by num_telefono desc
    ) as rn
  from t
) x
where rn = 1
```

Si, por ejemplo, tienes los siguientes datos:

```
 CTA_QUE_FACTURA  NUM_TELEFONO 
 ---------------- ------------ 
 123              666666666    
 456              0            
 456              777777777    
 789              0
```

El resultado que entrega es:

```
  CTA_QUE_FACTURA   NUM_TELEFONO   RN  
 ----------------- -------------- ---- 
  123               666666666      1   
  456               777777777      1   
  789               0              1
```

Puedes ver este ejemplo funcionando en [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8d7a64b5b23b49fba5f316c05a228a2a).